# Touching targets does nothing in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I keep staring at my code and wondering why touching my file does nothing:

```
FILES = file1 file2

myapp: $(FILES) docs/img/barline.svg
    cd docs; make html

docs/img/barline.svg: docs/notebooks/barlines.ipynb docs/data/smbinning
    cd docs/notebooks; jupyter nbconvert --execute --output-dir html barlines.ipynb
```

If I `touch docs/img/barline.svg` and run `make`, the jupyter command is not run (as it should be, shouldn't it?). The svg file is generated by running the jupyter command. If I delete it, everything works as expected, but touching seems to do nothing.

Comment: if you touch `docs/img/barline.svg` it runs `cd docs; make html`. Try touching `docs/notebooks/barlines.ipynb`, your jupyter command will be issued.

Comment: Oh Jean-François. This may be a sign to take a break from the computer. Thanks. Sure, that's how it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bah, I just spend all this time writing some other answer and it turns out I misinterpreted your problem, oops.

You say that you expect `jupyter` to run if you touch *barline.svg*.

Make uses the file timestamps to determine when to run. The rule, for non-phony targets, is simple: If any of the prerequisites is newer than the target, or the target doesn't exist, then the target is rebuilt. Otherwise, it is not. In your case:

```
docs/img/barline.svg: docs/notebooks/barlines.ipynb docs/data/smbinning
```

Touching the svg won't meet the conditions for that rule, since it is the target.

Make will only run if barlines.ipynb or smbinning is newer than barline.svg. So your expectations are off, touching barline.svg won't do anything except potentially cause any targets that use *it* as a prerequisite to be rebuilt themselves.

For this you'd have to touch barlines.ipynb or smbinning. That'll make them newer than barlines.svg and force it to rebuild. Or you could just delete barlines.svg, as you've discovered.

Make doesn't track build timestamps in any special place elsewhere, all its info comes from the filesystem, so if you touch a target it doesn't really have anything to compare it to to say "hey somebody modified the target, maybe I should rebuild it" (and you wouldn't want that behavior anyways, for other reasons).

Comment: I read your original answer and was quite impressed by it, also considering the speed with which you answered.